# How to set the background color of the active element in menudrawer

Tags: android, background

I am trying to create an application which implements a MenuDrawer (using the android-menudrawer library of SimonVT).

I started using, as a base, the example left menu. It uses an arrow to indicate which element is active.

My question is, how can I make the active item is displayed with a different color of background and not an image.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810316/highlighting-selected-item-in-menu-drawer-sliding-menu

Comment: The method setSelectionHandlerColorResource() is undefined for the type View, and the problem wasn't solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter put the following in side getView() `view.setSelectionHandlerColorResource(Set your color here);`

like :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view.setSelectionHandlerColorResource(Set your color here);
}
```

Comment: The method setSelectionHandlerColorResource() is undefined for the type View

Comment: Replace with equivalent method to set color for your method.

Comment: Yes, that may be an alternative, the method is view.setBackgroundColor(color). As I watched, with the library is not possible.

I'll have to implement some code to reset the default background and set the background of the selected item.